# MSI GS63 7RD wont start after a beep, but the keyboard light comes in

Tags: multi-boot, battery

So yes, this is relatively weak compared to my Mac from observing the result of taking it around in my backpack. I know I was forewarned against the durability of the hardware. I couldn't help it because the information was fully recognized only after I experienced a dent in the plastic cover near power button after a single carry-around in a backpack. Plus, this is a much-needed personal laptop with high-speed computing power at affordable price. Now I am overdue for return as well as a warranty for fix.

When I turn it on, I hear a 'beep' and the keyboard light turns in, but the screen remains pitch black.

This model has internal battery, so the common suggestions to detach/attach battery (https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=288794.0) and then restart with the cord plugged in would have to wait awhile for me to try. In the meantime.. does anyone have explanation or suggestion for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went to the MSI service center, and this model does not provide beep sounds to provide information.
It was merely a noise in the speaker that they weren't able to explain, nor had the professional attitude to search for a reason other than simply state that 'dual booting' could be the reason why.

It nonetheless corrected itself for unknown reason. Powering off in longer time has helped.

Answer (score 2):

The beep that you hear after starting the Laptop is the result of the Power On Self Test. I could not find the meanings of the beep codes in the manual of the Laptop that I downloaded from the MSI website. But one of the diagrams in the manual showed that it has an AMI BIOS. In AMI BIOS, 1 beep indicates a memory refresh timer error (Source - [AMI BIOS POST beep codes](http://www.ami.com/ami_downloads/AMIBIOS8_Checkpoint_and_Beep_Codes.pdf)). The solution they have stated is to reseat the RAM modules or replace them. If you are comfortable and know how to work with the hardware in a Laptop, you can try to remove the memory modules, clean around the contacts if dust has accumulated and reseat it again to see if that fixes the problem. That is the simplest thing to do according to the beep code.

Although what I stated above is probably the problem according to the beep code, you can connect an external monitor to the laptop to see if it works. This way you can verify if the Laptop screen is defective or not.

Comment: thank you so much for this. Do you think it is POST BIOS because the keyboard has the light on? Because otherwise I would have looked at Boot Block mode. Im not confident with handling internal battery models though. I still use Mac that constantly signals service-battery status. (;) I will deliver exactly this explanation to the MSI center who might still be able to give a hand.. hopefully.

Comment: I think that is the issue due to the beep that it emits. I don't think this is a battery issue.